# MVC - Call a controller method on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call a controller method when the user clicks a button, I also need a variable passed to this method. This is the code I have.

View:

```
 <input type="number" id="nbrMetric" name=metricNbr class="form-control" style="width:75px;" min="0">

@Html.ActionLink("Search", "InputTest", "CustomersController", new { @class = "btn btn-info", @Metric = "nbrMetric" })
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult InputTest(int Metric)
            {
               //Do Something

                return View();
            }
```

Comment: It probably should be `Customers` instead of `CustomersController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must send back a form the source code like this:
Model/Yourmodel.cs:

```
 public class FooModel
    {
        public int Metric { get; set; }
    }
```

Your controller:

```
public ViewResult InputTest() {

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitInputTest(FooModel model) { 
    //your code 
    //do stuff

    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

Your page:

```
    @model MVCWebApp.Models.FooModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>InputTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>


    @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitInputTest","Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>FooModel</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Metric, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Metric, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Metric, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may use ajax tecnologies

Comment: While your answer is correct, I don't see a reason for using a form and  a POST request for this given scenario where a simple link with a querystring parameter would be sufficient, unless of course there's a need to support a non-JS version of the page in which case a form would be necessary.

Comment: because i suppose that he need to get a value by input text

Comment: sure I got that part, but a) a form can have a GET action or b) the input value can be appended to a link using javascipt. Again, I'm not saying a form post is wrong, just that a GET request feels more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

This creates a button that when clicked will redirect to a controller/Action (Dashboard/Index)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default active" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Financial")'">Financial</button>
```

This adds the ability to send a parameter with the request:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default active" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Financial", "KsDashboard", new { id = 257 }))'">Financial</button>
```

here is the html produced :

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='/KsDashboard/Financial/123'" type="button">Financial</button>
```

Basically all you are doing is embedding an @Url.Action into the button's onclick event where the  @Url.Action simply returns the Url to the controlleryou wish to redirect to

[MS Documention for @Url.action:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the duplicate question that I've put in the comments the full explanation, in your case this should work:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "InputTest", "Customers", new { Metric = 3 }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

It's actually this overload of `Html.ActionLink`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: I tried using this code but I seem to be getting this error every time "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Metric' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult InputTest(Int32)' in 'FutatillDataAnalytics.Controllers.CustomersController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters", It seems it is not getting the value from the metric number input

Comment: I now understand what you are trying to do. `Html.ActionLink` is not suitable for posting parameters from an input to the controller, you should use a form with a submit button instead, something like C.Fasolin suggested.